# Barcode print in java while barcode scanner scans

Tags: java, barcode

I want to read the barcode and print it in a console in a simple java program as soon as the barcode scans on top of any barcode. Is there any way?

Answer (score -1):

```
final Scanner scanner;

    try 
    {
        scanner = new Scanner();

        try {
            scanner.release();
            scanner.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        scanner.open("MotorolaScannerUSB");

        scanner.claim(100);
        scanner.setDeviceEnabled(true);
        scanner.setDataEventEnabled(true);

        scanner.addDataListener(new DataListener() 
        {
            public void dataOccurred(DataEvent arg0) {
                Scanner scn = (Scanner) arg0.getSource();

                if (scn.equals(scanner)) {                      
                    try {
                        scanner.claim(100);
                        System.out.println(new String(scanner.getScanData()));
                        scanner.claim(100);
                        scanner.setDeviceEnabled(true);
                        scanner.setDataEventEnabled(true);
                    } catch (JposException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("error");
    }
```

Comment: Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.